# Cannot connect to YARN cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have created a Cloudera CDH (version 5.8.2) spark (version 1.6.0) YARN cluster on several AWS machines. Application code (part of a play application) present on a separate AWS machine and containing several spark functions has to be executed on the yarn cluster. For this, we have created a SparkConfig object in our application code which is used to connect to the yarn cluster. The driver program, however, throws an exception while connecting to the spark cluster. This is the configuration file that we are using in the server with the driver program:

```
object SparkConfig {
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:7077").appName("app").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
}
```

The application code and the SparkConfig object are the part of a play application. The error which we are receiving while running the play application is given below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class task.SparkConfig$
    at utility.ExpressionParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:14)
    at utility.ExprParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:115)
    at utility.ExprParser$$FastClassByGuice$$d3696456.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:78)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

What can be the reason for this error?

Edit:

Tried to set master to "yarn" as suggested by cricket_007. Received similar errors:

```
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Detected yarn cluster mode, but isn't running on a cluster. Deployment to YARN is not supported directly by SparkContext. Please use spark-submit.
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at task.SparkConfig$.<init>(SparkConfig.scala:6)
    at task.SparkConfig$.<clinit>(SparkConfig.scala)
    ... 91 more

2) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class task.SparkConfig$
  at utility.ExprParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:115)
  while locating utility.ExprParser
    for parameter 3 at task.Task.<init>(Task.scala:42)
  at task.Task.class(Task.scala:42)
  while locating task.Task
    for parameter 6 at service.WorkflowRunService.<init>(WorkflowRunService.scala:18)
  while locating service.WorkflowRunService
    for parameter 0 at controller.WorkflowRunController.<init>(WorkflowRunController.scala:21)
  while locating controller.WorkflowRunController
    for parameter 4 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:43)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class task.SparkConfig$
    at utility.ExpressionParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:14)
    at utility.ExprParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:115)
    at utility.ExprParser$$FastClassByGuice$$d3696456.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:78)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

3) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class task.SparkConfig$
  at utility.ExprParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:115)
  while locating utility.ExprParser
    for parameter 3 at task.Task.<init>(Task.scala:42)
  at task.Task.class(Task.scala:42)
  while locating task.Task
    for parameter 2 at service.DataSetService.<init>(DataSetService.scala:10)
  while locating service.DataSetService
    for parameter 2 at service.UserStoreService.<init>(UserStoreService.scala:17)
  while locating service.UserStoreService
    for parameter 0 at controller.UserStoreController.<init>(UserStoreController.scala:28)
  while locating controller.UserStoreController
    for parameter 5 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:43)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class task.SparkConfig$
    at utility.ExpressionParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:14)
    at utility.ExprParser.<init>(ExprParser.scala:115)
    at utility.ExprParser$$FastClassByGuice$$d3696456.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterI
```

Comment: If you are using YARN, don't you want `setMaster("yarn")`?

Comment: We tried it, it is not working. It is throwing the same error @cricket_007

Comment: There's not really enough details here, but 1) `spark://` is for standalone master, not YARN 2) You need to configure the Spark client to know about `YARN_CONF` and `HADOOP_CONF` -- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Comment: And your phrase "connect CDH and YARN to remote AWS cluster" doesn't make much sense... Are you trying to just `sc.textFile("s3://some_file")`?

Comment: I have updated the problem with more details. We are trying to use the SparkSession variable which we created in the SparkConfig object in our application code. This application code resides on a server which is maintained separately from the yarn cluster  @cricket_007

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but again `setMaster("yarn")` is what you **need** and you also **need** to set the configuration as the link I posted mention... I don't know what documentation you are reading that says `spark://` is correct.

Comment: Regardless, I know what you are trying to accomplish with that `SparkConfig` object. Where is the `main()` method? You've not said how you are running this code... Are you using `spark-submit`? `sbt` or `maven` to create a JAR file?

Comment: The application code belongs to a play application. We are using activator run to run it. It runs the spark program by using the configurations outlined in the SparkConfig object. @cricket_007

Comment: I tried setting master to yarn and changed the configuration settings. I again got error messages. I have edited the question accordingly.  @cricket_007

Comment: Error seems self-explanatory... `Deployment to YARN is not supported directly by SparkContext. Please use spark-submit`, in other words, your Play code may compile the Spark code into a JAR, and execute `spark-submit --master yarn` from invoking a shell command, though you can additionally try to use `setMaster("yarn-client")`